# How to get a map without boundary line?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get a Google Static Map without the white boundaries?

`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=terrain&sensor=false&size=512x512&&center=taiyuan&zoom=4&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off`

[image: Map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another style for feature:administrative|element:all:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=terrain&sensor=false&size=512x512&&center=taiyuan&zoom=4&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:administrative|element:all|visibility:off